# Read in text file in binary search with PHP without using ram memory

Tags: php

I need to make script that reads a file delimite by pipes "|" in with binary search without using memory ram. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
$handle = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
       // while reads line make binary search
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
   // error opening the file.
}
```

myfile.txt

```
  Name|Title|Andrew|TheBook1|July|TheChest|Carol|OneTime
```

Comment: read with generators (`yield`), see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php). Yielding lines have a low memory footprint.

Comment: @Xorifelse, how `yield` can be useful here? The `$line` is overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by a binary search. What are you searching. Are you searching within the line read or the whole file?

Comment: What kind of strange use case is this? Homework? Why not simply explode by "|" and search? The binary search requires the imput to be ordered, so you ll have to load it into memory anyway to order it...

Comment: @Patrick its for homework. I need to make it without using memory ram, I cant figure out an way to do this.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Because apparently memory usage is a concern for the OP. At the time of posting the comment however, the contents of "myFile.txt" were not available.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have to search in the role file

Comment: This may be the source of our confusion [as **binary search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) has a specific conortation. Please be more specific about what you are searching for and in what are you searching

Comment: @RiggsFolly I need to create an index for each field in the text file.Then I will have to search a field by primary key

Comment: I still have no real idea what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its homework, I ll give you some tips/steps, you figure out how to implement them :)

1. The binary search algorithm divides the the search into blocks. On each step, it chops the block which contains the element into half. That's why initially it aproximates very fast.
2. For that matter you need your data ordered alphabetically. The exercise says you have to implement a binary search without using memory. Doesn't say you can't use memory to order your data. So explode that string by "|", order it alphabetically and implode it again. There you have you ordered string.
3. For the actual algorithm you can't use memory, so you'll have to work with the filesystem only.
4. You need to know where the block your're searching in starts and finnishes.
5. I don't know if you are allowed to use variables in memory. If not, you'll have to write your variables to a file as well.
6. In that case, write functions like getBlockStart(), getBlockEnd(), setBlockStart, setBlockEnd() which read/write the values from a file.
7. Start the algorithm with `blockStart = <first element>, blockEnd = <lastELement>`
8. Chop in 2 parts and look in which part your element is based on the alphabetical order.
9. To check out the 10th, just read 10 elements of the file. That way you reach it.
10. Repeat until you find the element you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream_get_line` to use pipelines as delimiters.

```
while (($name = stream_get_line($handle, 0, '|')) !== false) {
   // if ($name == 'Carol') { ...
}
```

Comment: But I still need to use the binary search algorithm